# Are the Szpiro ratios of 37b1 over certain number fields {33,39,42,48,51,66}?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, number-fields

Related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181282/why-the-szpiro-conjecture-over-number-fields-doesnt-depend-on-the-discriminant).

According to [Hindry p.7 Conj 3.1](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~marc.hindry/MW-size.pdf)
and [Stein's notes](http://modular.math.washington.edu/mcs/archive/Fall2001/notes/12-10-01/12-10-01/node3.html) Szpiro's conjecture over number fields states that the Szpiro ratio is:

$$ \sigma_{E/K}=\frac{\log{|N_{K/Q}\Delta_{E/K}|}}{\log{|N_{K/Q} f_{E/K}}|}$$

Given $ \varepsilon >0$ there are only finitely many $ E/K$ with $ \sigma_{E/K}\geq 6+\varepsilon $. In particular, $ \sigma_{E/K}$ **is bounded**.

$\Delta_{E/K}$ is the minimal discriminant and $f_{E/K}$
is the conductor.

To my knowledge over the rationals the largest known Szpiro ratio
is about $9.01$.

Consider the elliptic curve with cremona label 37b1 and ainvariants
$[0, 1, 1, -23, -50]$. Over the rationals the discriminant is
$37^3$. Over the number field with defining polynomial
$x^{22} - 37^3$ the norm of the minimal discriminant is $37^{66}$ and the
norm of the conductor is $37$ while the global minimal model is the same
as over the rationals, giving Szpiro ratio $66$. If this pattern continue
for number fields of the form $x^n - 37^3$, the Szpiro ratio probably
will be unbounded.

Computation with sage, possibly assuming GRH since the number fields are not 
certified suggest the following large Szpiro ratios {33,39,42,48,51,66}:

```
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 33.00000 Delta= 37^33 f= 37 d_E/Q= 37^3  global minimal model= Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 + x^2 + (-23)*x + (-50) over Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^11 - 50653 
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 39.00000 Delta= 37^39 f= 37 d_E/Q= 37^3  global minimal model= Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 + x^2 + (-23)*x + (-50) over Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^13 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 42.00000 Delta= 37^42 f= 37 d_E/Q= 37^3  global minimal model= Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 + x^2 + (-23)*x + (-50) over Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^14 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 48.00000 Delta= 37^48 f= 37 d_E/Q= 37^3  global minimal model= Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 + x^2 + (-23)*x + (-50) over Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^16 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 51.00000 Delta= 37^51 f= 37 d_E/Q= 37^3  global minimal model= Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 + x^2 + (-23)*x + (-50) over Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^17 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 66.00000 Delta= 37^66 f= 37 d_E/Q= 37^3  global minimal model= Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 + x^2 + (-23)*x + (-50) over Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^22 - 50653
```

> Q1 Are the computations correct?
>
> Q2 Does increasing the degree of the number field continue to increase the ratio?
>
> Q3 (**New**) Is this a counterexample this formulation of Szpiro's conjecture? My concern is **bounded**, not infinitely many?

Working will large degree fields is not fast for me.

---

Small search found 46 ratios greater than $24$.

The largest is $134.6199$ from ainvariants $[1, 1, 1, -110, -880]$

```
 a_i= (1, 1, 1, -110, -880)  ratio= 134.6199 Delta= -1 * 3^304 * 5^19 f= 3 * 5 d_E/Q= -1 * 3^16 * 5  global minimal model= Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + x*y + y = x^3 + x^2 + (-110)*x + (-880) over Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^19 + 215233605
```

---

**Added** Addressing Jamie Weigandt answer.

With his code and possibly assuming GRH, I get the same ratio.

To assume GRH, replace `K.<a> = NumberField(x^11 - 50653)`
with `K.<a> = NumberField(x^11 - 50653,check=False)`. This avoids
certification of the NF with pari's `bnfcertify`.

Here is the output of

```
Nf.<w>=NumberField(x**D-d)
Nf.<w>=NumberField(x**D-d,check=False) #assume GRH
print 'a_i=',ai,' ratio=',szpiro_ratio(E2),Nf

a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 30.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^10 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 33.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^11 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 39.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^13 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 42.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^14 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 48.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^16 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 51.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^17 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 57.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^19 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 60.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^20 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 66.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^22 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 69.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^23 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 75.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^25 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 78.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^26 - 50653
a_i= [0, 1, 1, -23, -50]  ratio= 84.0 Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^28 - 50653
```

According to pari's documentation, the comment: `#Don't do this. It will take forever` probably will mean GRH fails for this NF, since in this case
pari's bnfcertify doesn't return.

Regarding his comment about Q2 and 32a1:  32a1 has $a_6=0$, so the
ratio degrades for trivial reasons. I didn't claim high ratio for it.

The claim that the ratio is bounded over number fields is from
[here](http://modular.math.washington.edu/mcs/archive/Fall2001/notes/12-10-01/12-10-01/node3.html) and [William Stein' notes](http://modular.math.washington.edu/mcs/archive/Fall2001/notes/12-10-01/12-10-01.tex)

Similar definition of the Szpiro's conjecture is in Silverman's 
The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, p. 275.

With the above notation, there is constant $k$, depending on $\epsilon$
and $K$ s.t.:

$$ N_{K/Q} \Delta_{E/K} \le k(N_{K/Q} f_{E/K})^{6+ \epsilon}\qquad (2) $$

Silverman asks "It is very interesting to ask how the constants $k$ appearing in these conjectures depend on the field $K$."

In analogy with the uniform abc conjecture, probably Silverman should take $k$ the discriminant of $K$.

Answer (score 7):

The correct discriminant ideal to compute is a locally defined ideal
$$\mathcal D_{E/K}^\text{min} = \prod_{\frak {p}} {\frak{p}}^{v_\frak{p}}$$
where $v_{\frak p}$ is the valuation of the discriminant of a **local minimal model** of $E$ at $p$. For general number fields, **global minimal models** do not exist. They exist if and only if the class number is 1.

This may or may not bring down your Szpiro ratios. If it doesn't, I still don't think this is inconsistent with Szpiro's conjecture since the finite set of counterexamples depends both on $\epsilon$ **and** the number field $K$. For every number field $K$ there is a finite (and sometimes non-empty) set of elliptic curves over $K$ with everywhere good reduction. These curves have conductor ideal $(1)$ so the Szpiro ratio can arguably be taken to be $\infty$.

I can't say whether your discriminant calculations are correct because I'm not sure how exactly you computed them, and working in these number fields is a bit too hard for me to do the calculations myself today. Here's code to compute the honest Szpiro ratio:

```
def szpiro_ratio(E):
    #Only works over number fields.
    N = E.conductor()
    nN = N.norm()
    S = N.prime_factors() 
    local_norms =[p.norm()^E.local_minimal_model(p).discriminant().ord(p) for p in S]
    nD = prod(local_norms)
    return log(RDF(abs(nD)))/log(RDF(abs(nN)))
```

To do these calculations, I would try:

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve('37b1')
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^11 - 50653)
sage: EK = E.base_extend(K)
sage: szpiro_ratio(EK) #Don't do this. It will take forever.
```

Then I would give up after 10 minutes because it would be clear that this is not a feasible approach for such high degree number fields. There might be a way around this difficulty with high degree number fields. I'd look at the code for local_minimal_model?? and try doing it by hand for primes in $K$ above $37$ to understand what's going it.

Here's an example where the code does work, and gives a negative answer to Q2.

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve('32a1').quadratic_twist(97)
sage: K.<a> = QuadraticField(97)
sage: L.<b> = NumberField(x^4 - 97)
sage: szpiro_ratio(E.base_extend(K))
2.4
sage: szpiro_ratio(E.base_extend(L))
2.25
```

**EDIT:** (Fixed some inaccuracies, and added a more reasonable explanation for the $2-2g$ term.

Look at the Shioda-Tate formula:
$$ N = \frac{D}{6} + 2 - 2g  + r + (h^{1,1} - \rho).$$
This is the elliptic surface analog of Szpiro's conjecture. Here $N$ is the conductor degree, $D$ is the discriminant degree, $r$ is the Mordell-Weil rank, $(h^{1,1} - \rho)$ is a non-negative number we don't need to worry about. We do have to worry about $2-2g$ where $g$ is the genus of the base curve.

There are two things this could be reflecting in the number field case.

(1) The negative $2g$ could be accounting for the difference between the minimal discriminant ideal and the discriminant ideal attached to a global model, since it measures the size of the Picard group of the base.

(2) (2-2g) could be correspond to something like $(1 + \epsilon)\log|\text{Disc}_{K/\Bbb Q}|$. Maybe both are related to the degree of some canonical divisor. I suppose this would be an Arakelov divisor in the number field case.

I think the second interpretation seems more reasonable, and agrees with what you're trying to say.

Comment: I fixed the code to deal with 37b1, not 37a1. My apologies to 37b, the most under-appreciated isogeny class of elliptic curves.

Comment: I get the same ratios with your code and possibly assuming GRH. Edited the question. Your code is fast if one doesn't certify the NF (assume GRH).

Comment: Do you think this leads to counterexample of Stein's formulation of Szpiro conjecture?

Comment: About unit conductor: won't in this case the discriminant be unit too leading to $\frac00$ which might not be $\infty$?

Comment: Regarding 0/0: That's why I said "arguably".
Regarding the reference you linked to: These are notes William Stein live-TeXed at a talk given by Matt Baker. It's unfair to William to call this *his* formulation of Szpiro's conjecture. Even then, Conjecture 3.1 is for a specific field $K$, while Theorem 3.2 is for all number fields. Everything seems to be written for a specific field $K$ here too: http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~marc.hindry/MarcJoe.pdf

Comment: My objection is about the wording **bounded** which appears in the Hindry paper from the other question: p.7, Conj. 3.1

Comment: I don't object to this, because $K$ is a fixed number field thoughout except in the remark about Weil restriction. So bounded is fine, provided you don't take my extremist viewpoint that the Szpiro ratios of curves with everywhere good reduction are $\infty$.

Comment: I well might be wrong.  Regarding 0/0:  IIRC this is known and in this case the ratio is taken $1$ (or other sufficiently small constant). Basically what I dislike in this formulation is that database of algebraic Szpiro record ratios doesn't make sense since it can be arbitrary large. Such databases make sense for rational Szpiro and (algebraic) abc. Silverman's generalization when patched possibly will make finding records very hard.

Comment: What algebraic Szpiro database are you talking about?

Comment: I mean the equivalent of Bart de Smit's database of abc triples http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~desmit/abc/index.php?sort=1 -- find E,K of large ratio, submit to the database.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. If I were constructing such a database, I would start over $\Bbb Q$ and sneak number fields into a later version of the database. It looks like there are a couple dozen curves over $\Bbb Q$ up to conductor 300000 with Szpiro ratio between 8 and 9. These would be attributed to Cremona until someone gave an earlier reference for them. Can you beat these examples over $\Bbb Q$? How do they compare to Nitaj's examples: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa85/aa8545.pdf

You might be able to find better examples using Ribet's theory of level optimization.

Comment: Re your potential NF database: If you compute the quality in this way, variations of this question might give you troubles ;) So far haven't found large ratios over the rationals.

Comment: btw, in your code for the ratio I object usage of `RDF`:  `sage:  RDF(10**500)/RDF(10**250)` returns _+infinity_

Comment: That's a fair objection. I moved everything to RDF quickly because I usually like to average these things, and then the sum is some awful symbolic expression.

Comment: Just for the record for computing the ratio, `RR` and similar to `RR=RealField(1000)` give better results than `RDF`.